# Connect two VPC via AWS transit gateway Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-cloudformation

Let I have two VPCs (VPC1, VPC2). Can someone propose how to write the Cloud Formation script properly to connect above VPCs and allows communication between VPCs using [AWS::EC2::TransitGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-transitgateway.html). I don't need VPC peering.